# Como inserir datas faltantes em um data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

Possuo uma serie temporal com 30 anos de dados que apresenta falhas de preenchimento. Como observado no exemplo abaixo, alguns dias não foram registrados (1961-08-19,1961-08-20,1961-08-21...). Como faço para identificar e inserir as datas faltantes na coluna "date", atribuindo "NA" para as demais colunas nessas datas em que não foi realizado monitoramento?

```
date        id  prec    tmax    tmin    tmed    urmax
1961-08-18  1   NA      23.53   14.90   27.90   36.33
1961-08-22  1   0.00    24.80   14.90   29.70   31.67
1961-08-24  1   1.00    24.37   15.30   28.80   37.33
1961-08-25  1   0.00    23.93   16.03   29.20   43.67
1961-08-26  1   0.00    25.97   15.27   31.60   30.33
1961-08-27  1   0.00    25.83   14.97   31.20   29.33
1961-08-29  1   0.00    24.60   15.87   30.20   39.33
1961-08-30  1   0.00    25.60   15.83   29.80   34.00
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma possível forma é você criar um data.frame com todas as datas possíveis:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

all_dates <- data_frame(
  date = seq(from = ymd("1968-01-01"), to = ymd("2018-01-01"), by = "1 day")
)
```

E em seguida dar `left_join` com o seu data.frame:

```
df$date <- ymd(df$date)
df <- all_dates %>%
  left_join(df, by = "date")
```

Answer (score 1):

uma opção é usar a biblioteca [padr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/padr/vignettes/padr.html)

```
dados <- structure(list(
       date = structure(c(-3058, -3054, -3052, -3051, -3050, -3049,
                          -3047, -3046), class = "Date"),
       id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
       prec = c(NA, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
       tmax = c(23.53, 24.8, 24.37, 23.93, 25.97, 25.83, 24.6, 25.6),
       tmin = c(14.9, 14.9, 15.3, 16.03, 15.27, 14.97, 15.87, 15.83),
       tmed = c(27.9, 29.7, 28.8, 29.2, 31.6, 31.2, 30.2, 29.8),
       urmax = c(36.33, 31.67, 37.33, 43.67, 30.33, 29.33, 39.33, 34)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

library(padr)
pad(dados)
```

---

```
pad applied on the interval: day
         date id prec  tmax  tmin tmed urmax
1  1961-08-18  1   NA 23.53 14.90 27.9 36.33
2  1961-08-19 NA   NA    NA    NA   NA    NA
3  1961-08-20 NA   NA    NA    NA   NA    NA
4  1961-08-21 NA   NA    NA    NA   NA    NA
5  1961-08-22  1    0 24.80 14.90 29.7 31.67
6  1961-08-23 NA   NA    NA    NA   NA    NA
7  1961-08-24  1    1 24.37 15.30 28.8 37.33
8  1961-08-25  1    0 23.93 16.03 29.2 43.67
9  1961-08-26  1    0 25.97 15.27 31.6 30.33
10 1961-08-27  1    0 25.83 14.97 31.2 29.33
11 1961-08-28 NA   NA    NA    NA   NA    NA
12 1961-08-29  1    0 24.60 15.87 30.2 39.33
13 1961-08-30  1    0 25.60 15.83 29.8 34.00
```